# How to Post New Record to Table and Pass that ID to another page to Create a Related Record

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, dropdown, razor-pages, viewdata

I am trying to Add a New Client on the Add Client (Create) page of my razor app. After the user fills out that page and clicks "Add Client" to commit the data to the Client.db, I want my app to then navigate to the Add Attendance (Create) page for my Attendance.db. The Attendance Create page has a dropdown list to select the client's ID (so that this page can also be accessed independently of the Create Client page).

What I would like to have happen is that the newly created client's ID would be the default to show in the dropdown when the Create Attendance page opens (when accessed by the Submit from the Add Client page (otherwise there should be none selected). Currently, my Create Client page will create the client record, but I'm not getting something set correctly to make the dropdown default to that client id. Can someone please assist? I have read about the asp-route-value in MS documentation as well as the ViewData info, but do not completely understand it yet. So, not sure if it is that or if I need to set the default value of the dropdown?

Here is a summary of the applicable code I have so far:

My Create.cshtml for adding a client and navigating to the Create Attendance page:

```
        <div>
            <button type="submit" asp-route-clientid="@ViewData["clientid1"]" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;">Add Client -> Go To Attendance</button>
            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width: 150px;">Back to Client List</a>
        </div>
```

My Create.cshtml.cs for my Create Client page

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Client.Add(Client);
            await _db.Client.AddAsync(Client);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Client added successfully.";
            ViewData["clientid1"] = Client.Id;
            return RedirectToPage("/Attendances/Create");
        }
        return Page();
    }
```

The client dropdown from the Create Attendance record page:

```
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Attendance.ClientId"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Attendance.ClientId" id="Select1" name="clientid" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayClientData.OrderBy(x => x.ClientDisplayName),"Id", "ClientDisplayName"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Client Id---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

My Create.cshtml.cs for the Create Attendance page:

```
[BindProperties]

public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    public Attendance Attendance { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }
    public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Panel> DisplayPanelData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Client> DisplayClientData { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Status> DisplayStatusData { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGet(int clientid)
    {
        var clientid1 = clientid;

        await _db.Panel.Select(a => a.PanelName).ToListAsync();
        DisplayPanelData = await _db.Panel.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Client.Select(a => a.Id).ToListAsync();
        DisplayClientData = await _db.Client.ToListAsync();
        await _db.Status.Select(a => a.StatusDesc).ToListAsync();
        DisplayStatusData = await _db.Status.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.Attendance.Add(Attendance);
            await _db.Attendance.AddAsync(Attendance);
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = "Client Attendance added successfully.";
            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
        return Page()
}
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to use a query parameter. `return RedirectToPage($"/Attendances/Create?ClientID={Client.Id}");` From there you can read it out of the query params string and process it on the Create page using `Request.QueryString["ClientID"]` I believe. You may need t polish up the implementation here as I'm not overly familiar with Razor, however that should get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple working demo you could follow:

Client/Create.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Client.CreateModel

<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px;">Add Client</button>
</form>
```

Client/Create.cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        ViewData["clientid1"] = 3;
        return RedirectToPage("/Attendances/Create", new { clientid = ViewData["clientid1"] });
    }
}
```

Attendances/Create.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Attendances.CreateModel

<select asp-for="Attendance.ClientId" id="Select1" name="clientid" class="form-select">
    <option value="" selected disabled>---Select Client Id---</option>
    <option value="1">client1</option>
    <option value="2">client2</option>
    <option value="3">client3</option>
</select>
```

Attendances/Create.cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    public Attendance Attendance { get; set; } = new Attendance();

    public void OnGet(int clientid)
    {
        Attendance.ClientId=clientid;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. Looks like this time it was me making it more difficult than it had top be!

Comment: I do have one question regarding your solution. Now, with that code in place, when I click the Add Attendance button, the attendance record will not be bound in the database. It simply returns to the Index page w/o adding the new attendance record. Is it the " = new Attendance()" part of the code that you added that could be causing my post to the _db.Attendance.Add(Attendance); NOT to work?

Comment: Hi @MelB, `= new Attendance()` will not influence the database store. Your code not working may be caused by the `Attendance` do not pass to backend successfully, you can debug your code and check if it get the value. Because your select is name of `name="clientid"`, you need remove it, the tag helper `asp-for="Attendance.ClientId"` will correctly generate `name="Attendance.ClientId"`. And be sure all the inputs which belong to Attendance model have correct element attribute `asp-for="Attendance.PropertyName"`.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what it was. Once I removed the name="clientid" everything else worked fine.

Comment: I have another question if you get this. How do I pass this client Id BACK to the Edit Client page once I have created the panel? I have tried several different things, but I think I am once again making this more difficult than necessary. I am receiving a null exception error when trying to send it back. I'm following your example above (using a different variable name) when trying to send the ID back to the Edit Client page from the Create Panel page.

Comment: Hi @MelB, You need be sure send the id like what I did in `RedirectToPage`. Then be sure set a property or a model which contains such id, and set the value with the passed value. In the edit page, use asp-for="Id".

Comment: Hi @MelB, if still not clear, you can post a new thread with your code for help.